# Execute functions in order

Tags: jquery, function

I want to execute 3 functions in a certain order and I do this:

```
function nextPage() {
    var loading_temp = $('#loading_temp');

    loading_temp.show()
        .queue(function() {
            nextPage980()
                .queue(function() {
                    loading_temp.hide();
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            $(this).dequeue();
        });         
}
```

The '#loading_temp' shows up and then the function executes, but the last function (hide the loading gif) does not execute!

Chrome gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'queue' of undefined

The nextPage980() function is this:

```
function nextPage980() {
        var ajax_heading = $('#ajax_heading');          
        var cur_heading = $('#cur_heading');            
        var temp_heading = $('.temp_heading');
            var temp_heading_first = temp_heading.filter(':first');         
        var loading_temp = $('#loading_temp');

        var htmlHeader = "Εγκαταστάσεις";           

        ajax_heading.attr('class', 'next_temp');        
        cur_heading.css({'margin-right' : '20px'}).after('<div id="cur_heading" class="temp_heading" data-tempPos="2"><h1 class="page_heading"><span class="heading_span">' + htmlHeader + '</span></h1></div>')        
            .queue(function() {
                ajax_heading.animate({'margin-left' : '-1000px'}, 1000, 'easeInExpo')               
                    .queue(function() {
                        temp_heading_first.remove();                        
                        cur_heading.removeAttr('style');                        
                        ajax_heading.attr('class', 'cur_temp').removeAttr('style');                                                     
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    });
                $(this).dequeue();
            });     
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't return anything it's `undefined`. So everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return a jquery object from `nextPage980`. Add an unconditional `return $(this);` to the end. As it stands you're calling `queue` on the current return value, which is nothing (hence your error message).